# How to create a gridview with 4 level grouping

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, gridview

In my sharepoint application, i must to create a view with 4 level grouping in a page

```
+- Level 1
  +- Level 2
    +- Level 3
       +- Level 4
```

Help me. Can i use SPGridview or ASP Gridview.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the `4` levels are fixed you can create a nested gridview control. **[Editable nested gridview (All in one)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20047/Editable-Nested-GridView-All-in-One)**
2. You would just drop gridviews inside gridviews on a template field column
3. Then, just use `FindControl` on `RowDataBoundEvent` of your parent gridview, find the nested gridview control if true, then DataBind it with your datasource
4. If you are talking about N-levels **[this](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Multilevel-N-Level-Nested-GridView-GridView-inside-GridView-in-ASPNet-with-Paging.aspx)** may help you further